# Concurrent access to list: what happens if objects are removed or the list is set to null?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have a List with objects **List<> my_objects**. Several threads can change this list. Let's suppose that I do not have any locking mechanism for controlling the access to the list.

What happens, if I'm working with an object of the list and suddenly another thread sets the array to null?

```
    MyObject o = my_objects[i];

    //now a second thread has set my_objects to null
    o.myMethod();
```

Will a NullPointerException occur?

Furthermore, what happens if a second thread removes the considered object from the list while I'm working with it in the first thread?

```
   //second thread:
   //y = i
   MyObject o2 = my_objects[y];

   my_objects.Remove(o2);
```

Comment: You'll most likely get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated."

Comment: Is it an array or a list? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Look into the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace objects... you could have a direct drop in that would be thread safe.  That doesn't answer a question, just thought I would point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyObject o = my_objects[i];

//now a second thread has set my_objects to null, and/or invoked my_objects.Remove(o)
o.myMethod();
```

That's fine. The variable `my_objects` holds *references* to objects, not the objects themselves. When you make a new variable `o`, it holds a second reference to the same object. Then you clear `my_objects`, which means you can't refer to the actual object through `my_objects` anymore. But that doesn't change the fact that you still have `o`, and you can still refer to the actual object through `o`. (And *that* in turn implies that the object itself still exists. C# is a garbage-collected language, which, to a first approximation means that objects are guaranteed to stick around until you're done with them. Non-managed C++ is different in this respect, and Objective-C is different in yet a third way. Not that you asked.)

Effectively, in this respect, *references to* `MyObject` behave just like primitive types like `int`. If I have an array of `int`, and I do

```
int oi = my_ints[i];
```

then I can do whatever I want with `my_ints` (clear it, remove items from it) and that won't change the fact that `oi` still exists.

The thing about *reference types* like `MyObject`, and the reason you got confused enough to ask this question, is that with `MyObject` both variables (`o` and `my_objects[i]`) still *refer to* the same actual object, so if you mutate the object via `my_objects[i].gainSpiderPowers()`, you'll see the effects of that mutation no matter whether you're looking via `my_objects[i]` or via `o`.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens, if I'm working with an object of the list and suddenly another thread sets the array to null?

Nothing, if you've already copied the reference in question to a local variable.

You'll get an exception if another thread sets `my_objects` to null *before* this line:

```
MyObject o = my_objects[i]; // my_objects must be non-null
```

The value of `o` is just a reference to the object. It has *no* knowledge of the list or array you happened to get it from. The collection could be garbage collected, anything could happen - neither the reference nor the object itself is affected.

(The removal of the element from the list could cause problems, as Henk says - `List<T>` is not thread safe - but that's a different matter from the one I understand you were asking about.)

Comment: thank you. I'm interested in both cases (setting to null and removal of the object).

Comment: @curiosity: In both cases nothing about the variable `o` or its value changes.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you've already got a reference to the object, and changing the list has no effect on the object itself. You won't get any exceptions because of the state of the object itself (e.g. NullReferenceException).

However you may get other exceptions because of the concurrent access to the `List<T>`. You should either use locking when accessing the list or, even better, take a look at the classes in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Not true. `my_objects[i]` is only safe when other threads read simultaneously. When they also write (mutate) all bets are off.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the way I read the question, the OP is concerned about list changes _past_ that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a ReadOnlyCollection.  It is located in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace.